# Error when trying to import a ECC private key with python

Tags: python, cryptography

I have a purpose to create the same private key / public key based on an input string:

I am facing a problem when trying to import a ECC private key:

This private key was created from a hash:

```
import sys
import base64
import string
from Crypto.PublicKey import ECC
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.IO import PEM
input = sys.argv[1]
input_hash = SHA256.new(input)
private_pem = PEM.encode(input_hash.digest(), "PRIVATE KEY",  passphrase=None, randfunc=None)
key = ECC.import_key(private_pem)
```

bellow the trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "request.py", line 29, in
>   
>       key = ECC.import_key(private_pem)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\ECC.py", line 792, in
>   import_key
>       return _import_der(der_encoded, passphrase)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\ECC.py", line 725, in
>   _import_der
>       raise ValueError("Not an ECC DER key") ValueError: Not an ECC DER key

Anyone have an idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are standard on how keys should be encoded. It seems the `import_key` method validates that it is ASN.1 DER encoded, after stripping the *ASCII armor* supplied by the PEM encoding.

PEM consists of a header- and footer line, in this case the *generic* `PRIVATE KEY` header. This line doesn't indicate the type of the key. Therefore it uses the PKCS#8 wrapped representation of the key, which contains an identifier to indicate the key type. This PKCS#8 has been specified by the ASN.1 notation which indicates the *structure* of the key and DER which specified how the values are encoded using that structure. PKCS#8 may also wrap the key, but as you've not specified a password I assume it isn't.

Now inside the PKCS#8 there should be a representation of the key itself. For ECC usually X9.62 is used. This is again an ASN.1 / DER encoding of the key. It *doesn't just contain the private key value*. It also contains a reference to the ECC domain parameters used - or the domain parameters in full. You will have to create this structure yourself if you use the method you've specified. How the structure is to be encoded is specified in [section 3 of RFC-5915](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915).

It seems that you should be able to create a shortcut and only supply a X9.62 public key as specified in the RFC to `import_key` (check the documentation!). In that case use `PRIVATE EC KEY` instead of `PRIVATE KEY` in the header and footer line. See the answer of [Thomas](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84331/2651) here for more info on the structure - or just reference the RFC.

You may need an ASN.1 or DER library as ASN.1 encoding/decoding is not for the weak of heart (and is a common source for out of bounds, buffer overruns and integer overflow errors in many implementations, negating most of the security that crypto can provide).

Comment: Apologies, my Python environment is not operative at the moment, I can only explain, not code.